# asp.net reading config file from class library

Tags: asp.net

Hi I a custom config file which I am having problems reading from a class project, is there a simple way to do this? the path does not seem to be getting picked up in code, where as this works in a web project

Comment: Post the code you are using now. Are you using `ConfigurationManager`? There are samples on msdn.

Comment: If your real problem is the one in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202525/asp-net-mvc-test-project-cannot-find-windsor-file you won't get any good answers with this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suppose that you are reading .config files from an established path, i.e. the path of your class project. There really isn't enough information in the question, however this looks revealing: the path does not seem to be getting picked up in code, where as this works in a web project.
If that is the case, I would suggest you take a look at http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2007/12/14/How-To-Load-an-Embedded-Resource-From-A-DLL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The .NET configuration system doesn't natively support class libraries having their own config and reading those. The base assumption is that the config comes from the host app - either a `Myapp.exe.config` for a WPF, Winforms or console app, or the `web.config` for a web app.

There are ways to grab config information from custom config files - but again: those are *not* the standard, supported .NET configuration scenarios, so you'll have to do a lot of work yourself and you might run into issues.

To see how this would work, check out You should also check out [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx) written by Jon Rista - excellent material.